# Qt Canvas3D: Calling gl.colorMask or gl.depthMask, even with gl.TRUE for all args, breaks all further rendering

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

I've distilled this to a completely trivial testcase. First I setup all low-level stuff like shaders, vertex buffers and matrices. Then I enable all four arguments of `gl.colorMask`. Then I draw a white triangle. The results is a window that alternates between all black and white (flickers) at a high frequency. I.e. completely buggy.

Removing the `gl.colorMask` call fixes it, and, in my real app, lets all other GL functionality work fine.

**Side note:** the described result is from my minimal testcase. In my real app calling `gl.colorMask` breaks all further rendering too, but does not cause flicker - instead, the entire Canvas3D becomes transparent (there I have background item behind the Canvas3D, and I clear the GL context to a transparent color, unlike in this testcase, in which I clear to black). The items outside the Canvas3D in my real app are not broken by the `gl.colorMask` call - its influence is limited within the Canvas3D.

**Platforms note:** This has been reproduced on:

- Windows 7 with an Intel GPU
- Ubuntu Linux with an nVidia GPU
- custom built Linux with an ARM Mali GPU

**My code:**

I based my testcase on the `textureandlight` sample app bundled with Qt. Since mine is a derived work, I have to first post the license terms here:

```
/****************************************************************************
**
** Copyright (C) 2016 The Qt Company Ltd.
** Contact: https://www.qt.io/licensing/
**
** This file is part of the QtCanvas3D module of the Qt Toolkit.
**
** $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
** Commercial License Usage
** Licensees holding valid commercial Qt licenses may use this file in
** accordance with the commercial license agreement provided with the
** Software or, alternatively, in accordance with the terms contained in
** a written agreement between you and The Qt Company. For licensing terms
** and conditions see https://www.qt.io/terms-conditions. For further
** information use the contact form at https://www.qt.io/contact-us.
**
** BSD License Usage
** Alternatively, you may use this file under the terms of the BSD license
** as follows:
**
** "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
** modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
** met:
**   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
**   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
**     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
**     distribution.
**   * Neither the name of The Qt Company Ltd nor the names of its
**     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
**     from this software without specific prior written permission.
**
**
** THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
** "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
** A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
** OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
** SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
** DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
** THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
** (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
** OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
**
** $QT_END_LICENSE$
**
****************************************************************************/
```

And now for the actual source.

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // the following line enables Google's ANGLE layer,
    // since Qt Quick is really buggy on my Intel GPU unless I enable it.
    // But that's not what is causing the problem, because the problem
    // also occurs on non-Windows platforms, on which this line is a no-op
    // and OpenGL calls are executed directly rather than being translated
    // to DirectX.
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView viewer;
    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    viewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml:*

```
Canvas3D {
    width: 800
    height: 500

    id: canvas3d

    onInitializeGL: {
        GLCode.initializeGL();
    }

    onPaintGL: {
        GLCode.paintGL();
    }

    onResizeGL: {
        GLCode.resizeGL();
    }
}
```

*GLCode.js:*

```
Qt.include("gl-matrix.js")

var gl;
var vertexPositionAttribute;
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var pMatrix  = mat4.create();
var pMatrixUniform;
var mvMatrixUniform;
var colorUniform; // unused. removing it produced a weird error. please ignore.

function initializeGL() {
    gl = canvas3d.getContext("canvas3d");

    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    initShaders();

    initBuffers();
}

function resizeGL()
{
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas3d.width, canvas3d.height);
    mat4.perspective(pMatrix, degToRad(45), canvas3d.width / canvas3d.height, 0.1, 500.0);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
}

function degToRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function paintGL() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0, 0, -10.0]);

    gl.colorMask(gl.TRUE, gl.TRUE, gl.TRUE, gl.TRUE);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

function initBuffers()
{
    var cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    cubeVertexPositionBuffer.name = "cubeVertexPositionBuffer";
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                new Float32Array([
                                        -1.0, -1.0,
                                        1.0, -1.0,
                                        1.0,  1.0
                                 ]),
                gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                  new Uint16Array([0,  1,  2]),
                  gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function initShaders()
{
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl,
                                  "attribute highp vec3 aVertexPosition;  \
                                                                         \
                                  uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;                \
                                  uniform mat4 uPMatrix;                 \
                                                                         \
                                  void main(void) {                      \
                                      gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0); \
                                  }"
                                 , gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl,
                                   "void main(void) {                  \
                                        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);           \
                                    }"
                                   , gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();

    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        console.log("Could not initialise shaders");
        console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);

    pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
}

function getShader(gl, str, type) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.log("JS:Shader compile failed");
        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}
```

**Required js libary:** "glMatrix 2.2.2". I can't find this exact version from its official site, but you can get almost the same version (2.2.1) [here](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/tree/v2.2.1/dist).

I've also **uploaded the complete testcase project** [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz34FkgNISnZd2lPX1hRWDE3bEU), if you want to run it more easily. (the download button is at the top-right corner of that page). Please ignore the confusing project name, it's a leftover.

**My theory** is that this is a bug in the Canvas3D's OpenGL JavaScript bindings but I'm not sure.

## Edit: found a workaround:

I managed to workaround this by replacing my call of:

```
gl.colorMask(gl.FALSE, gl.FALSE, gl.FALSE, gl.FALSE);
```

(which is what it looks like in my real app) with this:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ZERO, gl.ONE);
```

I'd still like to know why gl.colorMask breaks stuff this way though.

## Edit: found the same problem with the depth mask:

As a separate but related bug, replacing the gl.colorMask call in my testcase with a `gl.depthMask(gl.FALSE)` (or even `gl.depthMask(gl.TRUE)`) also causes rendering problems. In that case it's not the whole screen that's flickering - instead, only the triangle flickers. Of course to reproduce the bug one should also enable (rather than disable) depth testing in initializeGL, and to clear `DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` too, rather than just `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`.

That one might be harder to find a proper workaround for, although in my specific case I may get away with disabling gl.DEPTH_TEST altogether for this rendering stage in my algorithm (which has the side effect of disabling depth writes as well)

Comment: I'm not familiar with QML but is there a way to debug into the `Context3D` implementation? Aside from the invocation of `colorMask` being completely unnecessary in your code I don't see how anyone here can answer without confirming the supposed bug in Qt. From the standpoint of the GLES state machine, your call is a no-op. Also, why are you disabling depth testing and clearing of the depth buffer? Is there any reason to that?

Comment: Re debugging into the `Context3D` implementation: I could do that, but I don't want to invest the time, given that I was able to replace my gl.colorMask call (in my real app where it's not a no-op) with a suitable glBlendFunc call which works for me. Re "completely unnecessary": sure, that's just a testcase that shows that it breaks stuff instead of being no-op. Re disabling depth stuff: I did it to simplify the testcase by cutting out features it doesn't need.

Comment: Ok, but abusing blending to mimic color write masking? Is that really how you want to proceed?

Comment: @thokra: Beats spending hours of company time to achieve ultimately the same result :) btw I edited my workaround into the end of the answer if you're interested.